# How to programmatically simulate touch event in Meego?

Tags: qt, touch, meego

I need to use an input text file as an alternative to touch input for a meego based device , I want to know how I can do this.

What input parameters are actually passed by the touch screen on meego device to invoke the respective touch event?

Whether the input type is coordinates, screen, any id?

I know I can use `QTouchEvent` class instance and pass it `QApplication:: sendEvent()`,
but how to programatically post the touch event which will be processed just as an actual human touch?

Please suggest alternative solution.

Thanks

Comment: what's the problem with posting a `QTouchEvent` to the event queue, as you mention above? Are you trying to achieve any extra behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem on linux touch device. What you are trying to do is probably equivalent to human touch.

You can also try posting `QMouseEvent` using `QCoreApplication::postEvent()`

In `QMouseEvent`, you can pass `x` and `y` coordinates of the location you want to click.